# Show that the function $f: [0,1] \rightarrow C$ is a measurable function.

Tags: real-analysis

This is an exercise that I need to solve but I couldn't, is number 7 of section 2.6 of the book: A user friendly introduction to lebesgue measure and integration by Gail S. Nelson.

$f$ is the cantor function.

[image]

Comment: try to verify that $f$ is monotonically increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: let $x =\sum \frac {x_n} {2^{n}} <y=\sum \frac {y_n} {2^{n}} $. Consider the least integer $n$ such that $x_n \neq y_n$. Then $x_n=0,y_n=1$ and $x_j=y_j$ for $j <n$. Now consider the images of these two points. Note that $2(y_n-x_n)=2$. Using the fact that $\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac 2 {3^k}= \frac 1 {3^{n}}$ show that $f(x)\leq f(y)$. Since any increasing function is measurable the proof is complete.

Comment: I just put a picture of the definition.